# SEHException when calling DeleteTimerQueueTimer

Tags: c#, timer

I'm using a Timer class that wraps `CreateTimerQueueTimer` and `DeleteTimerQueueTimer`.

Here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using MyCompany.Internal;
using TimerCallback = MyCompany.Internal.TimerCallback;

public class Timer : IDisposable
{
    public Timer()
    {
        this.callback = this.ticked;
        this.autoReset = true;
        Computer.ChangeTimerResolutionTo(1);
        this.priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
    }

    public virtual event EventHandler Elapsed;

    public virtual bool AutoReset
    {
        get
        {
            return this.autoReset;
        }

        set
        {
            this.autoReset = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual ThreadPriority Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return this.priority;
        }

        set
        {
            this.priority = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual void Start(int interval)
    {
        if (interval < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("interval", "Interval must be at least 1 millisecond.");
        }

        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.started, 1, 0) == 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        NativeMethods.CreateTimerQueueTimer(
            out this.handle,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            this.callback,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            (uint)interval,
            (uint)interval,
            CallbackOptions.ExecuteInTimerThread);
    }

    public virtual void Stop()
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.started, 0, 1) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        NativeMethods.DeleteTimerQueueTimer(IntPtr.Zero, this.handle, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        this.Stop();
    }

    private void ticked(IntPtr parameterPointer, bool unused)
    {
        if (!this.AutoReset)
        {
            this.Stop();
        }

        Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = this.Priority;
        var elapsed = this.Elapsed;
        if (elapsed != null)
        {
            elapsed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private int started;
    private IntPtr handle;
    private volatile bool autoReset;
    private ThreadPriority priority;
    private readonly TimerCallback callback;
}
```

The problem is, after awhile I'm getting an SEHException when calling Start and Stop simultaneously from multiple threads.  The `Interlocked.CompareExchange` methods should prevent DeleteTimerQueueTimer from being called once after `Stop()` is called, right?  Even if `Stop()` is called simultaneously from different threads?

The `SEHException` is being thrown at `DeleteTimerQueueTimer()`; I assume it's because it's trying to delete a timer that has already been deleted, making the handle invalid.  Doesn't the `CompareExchange` prevent `DeleteTimerQueueTimer` from being called more than once, even by multiple threads simultaneously?

Comment: How many timer instances do you create? Does each thread its own time instance?

Comment: One timer instance is used for all threads.  Each thread is raising an event that `Stop()`s the timer at the start of its handling method and re-`Start()`s the timer at the end of its handling method.  Basically, I want to refresh stuff on the screen when the thread raises the event, or the timer expires (in case no threads raise an event for awhile/ever).

Answer (score 1):

The function Interlocked.CompareExchange prevent the variable 'started' from modified at same time from 2 threads, but the handle of the timer is the real one you want to protected, but the code fails to do in some cases.

For example, thread A call the start function, it execute the function Interlocked.CompareExchange and then this.started is 1; at this time thread A call the stop function, it sees that 'started' is one, so it will call function DeleteTimerQueueTimer to delete the timer, while the timer might not be created yet and the handle is invalid.

So you should protect the handle of the timer